# telnet stream unknown escape code

Tags: terminal, telnet, xterm

I have a task that involves parsing telnet stream. All works well until my client receives unknown to me escape sequence **ESC[15X**. I have checked many documents explaining what do escape codes mean and should do, but none of them contained the one mentioned. When I test the escape code in terminal window it seems to not do anything. If anyone has a clue or knows where to look it up, it would help me greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is used to erase characters.  [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) lists it:

```
CSI Ps X  Erase Ps Character(s) (default = 1) (ECH).
```

where

```
ESC [
     Control Sequence Introducer (CSI  is 0x9b).
```

It was introduced by DEC VT220, and is supported in xterm and a few other terminal emulators.